# How to set/serialize values based on results from multiple rows / multiple columns in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table in which I want to calculate two columns values based on results from multiple rows / multiple columns. The primary key is set on the first two columns (tag,qid).
I would like to set the values of two fields (serial and total).
The "serial" column value is unique for each (tag,qid) so if I have 2 records with same tag, I must have record one with serial# 1 and record two with serial# 2 and so on. The serial must be calculated with accordance to priority field in which higher priority values must start serializing first.

the "total" column is the total number of each tag in the table

I would like to do this in plain SQL instead of creating a stored procedure/cursors, etc...

the table below shows full valid settings.

```
                                 
 +----+----+--------+-------+-----+  
 |tag |qid |priority|serial |total|  
 +--------------------------------+  
 |abc | 87 |  99    |  1    |  2  |  
 +--------------------------------+  
 |abc | 56 |  11    |  2    |  2  |  
 +--------------------------------+  
 |xyz | 89 |  80    |  1    |  1  |  
 +--------------------------------+  
 |pfm | 28 |  99    |  1    |  3  |  
 +--------------------------------+  
 |pfm | 17 |  89    |  2    |  3  |  
 +--------------------------------+  
 |pfm | 64 |  79    |  3    |  3  |  
 +----+----+--------+-------+-----+
```

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can readily return a result set with this information using window functions:

```
select tag, qid, priority,
       row_number() over (partition by tag, qid order by priority desc) as serial,
       count(*) over (partition by tag, qid) as total
from table t;
```